# JDBC Connection pooling issue - Deadlock while getting connection

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, connection-pooling

I am using JDBC connection pooling in Tomcat. To retrieve connections I have defined a connection factory as below:

```
public class ConnectionManager {

   // reference to the ConnectionManager
   private static ConnectionManager instance = null;
   // Connection to MySQL database
   private Connection connect = null;

   private static DataSource ds = null;
   // Logger
   public static final Logger logger = Logger
         .getLogger(ConnectionManager.class);

   static {

      try {
         Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
         Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
         ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/ConnectionManager");
      } catch (NamingException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   /**
    * Private Constructor .. since its a singleton
    * 
    */
   private ConnectionManager() {

   }

   public static ConnectionManager getInstance() {
      if (instance == null) {
         instance = new ConnectionManager();
      }
      return instance;
   }

   public Connection getDbConnection() {
      Connection conn = null;

      try {
         synchronized (DataSource.class) {

            conn = ds.getConnection();
         }
      } catch (SQLException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return conn;
   }

   public void closeDbConnection() throws SQLException {
      conn.close();
   }
}
```

Now I see that my code always gets stuck at `conn = ds.getConnection();` line. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. From my DAO methods I am using the following to get connection: `conn = ds.getConnection();`

Clearly its a multi-threading issue. What should I do?

Comment: Show us the real code. This one doesn't compile.

Comment: Are you sure that the database connection pool has connections left that it can hand out ?

Comment: In your DAO methods you are calling `ds.getConnection`? Are you sure about that? Given the code you showed I am surprised you are not calling `ConnectionManager.getDbConnection`. There are *several* problems with this code - but I have to ask a quick question - why are you synchronizing on the DataSource class?

Comment: sorry preception my mistake its actually ConnectionManager.getInstance().getDbConnection(); i am using in the client code. actually i beleive that Datasource is the critical object in this case and therefore, this synchronization. please let me know what other problems you see..

Comment: @arya - ok thats clearer now. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of your class seems geared around retrieving the JNDI datasource and using it to create connections. Not necessarily a bad idea but in this case you have introduced some bugs into your program with the additional complexity.

First off, your singleton is not a singleton. Your are not synchronizing the `getInstance` method so its possible to multiple threads to invoke this method at the same time. The best method in Java  (unfortunately) for implementing singletons is via an enum:

```
public enum ConnectionManager {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

Your second significant issue is that you are synchronizing on a class that you don't explicitly control. There is nothing preventing third party JARs or even other classes in your own application from synchronizing on the DataSource class, making it a rife target for deadlocking issues. I would take out all the superfluous methods from the class and remove the synchronize block:

```
public enum ConnectionManager {
    INSTANCE;

    private DataSource ds = null;

    ConnectionManager() {
      try {
         final Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
         final Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
         ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/ConnectionManager");
      } catch (NamingException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

   public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
      if(ds == null) return null;

      return ds.getConnection();
   }
}
```

Now, most datasource implementations are thread safe in my experience, so the above code should work most of the time. But, we shouldn't rely on implementations we cannot control, so lets add a *safe* synchronization to the code, like so:

```
public enum ConnectionManager {
    INSTANCE;

    private DataSource ds = null;
    private Lock connectionLock = new ReentrantLock();

    ConnectionManager() {
      try {
         final Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
         final Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
         ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/ConnectionManager");
      } catch (NamingException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

   public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
      if(ds == null) return null;

      Connection conn = null;
      connectionLock.lock();
      try {
          conn = ds.getConnection();
      } finally {
          connectionLock.unlock();
      }

      return conn;
   }
}
```

You don't have to add wrapper methods to close the connection, that is the responsibility of the calling code. Good luck.

Comment: Thx a ton for ur comprehensive reply.. i did what u said but same problem exactly. it gets hung on ds.getConnection after a while.

Comment: by the way i am using the following paramters for my pool in context.xml:<Resource name="jdbc/ConnectionManager"
            auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
username="root" password="root" removeAbandoned="true"  removeAbandonedTimout="30" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/sicad?autoReconnect=true"  minIdle="10" maxActive="80" maxIdle="20" suspectTimeout="10" timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="3000"
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="6000" 
     />do u see something a miss here.

Comment: The datasource configuration looks fine. In all likelihood you are running out of connections in the pool. Are you holding unto the connections for long periods of time? And are you closing them once they are no longer needed?

Comment: To eliminate other sources of potential deadlock, try setting your maxActive to 0. If the problem goes away with that change then its pretty much a certainty that you are leaking connections.

Comment: actually i tried what u said but its not working it seems. still getting stuck at getconnection method after some times. isnt there any configuration parameter which would return the connection in case the connection wasnt closed properly?

Answer (score 0):

@arya, seems like you are having the problem of connection leak,  and because of that the pool is getting exhausted and the code just waits till it gets a new connection, To analyze the problem , use any of the database monitoring tools, or manually try to trace the leak (The point in code where you have consumed a connnection but forgot to return it to the pool after use).

Comment: akash, yes it could be leak but then again in my context.xml i am using suspectTimeout="60" , timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000" so after 60 seconds it should have closed the connection and replaced it with the new connection. isnt it right?

Comment: @arya , yes thats correct, but some time back i faced the similar problem , and in my scenario , the connections were bieng consumed in  a loop and all the connections bieng active simulataneously were not bieng reverted back to the pool, the auto pull  will do it only when the connection object is out of scope , but at that instance , all the connections were active and hence waiting for new ones :( .

Comment: what do u suggest akash, how do i close the connection? i am directly calling myconnection.close().

Comment: Yes thats the correct way to release the connection , but the problem seems like at some point of code you have missed to close the connection , or may be some exceptional flow (, like in case of exception the connection ) is not bieng closed and hence the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would say first try out your `dataSource` is working or not with a test source.
I suggest look at Apache Tomcat JNDI Data Resource How To, for [Apache Tomcat 6.0](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) and for [Apache Tomcat 7.0](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html).

Look at the instructions carefully and analyse what's going wrong in your code, then update your question with specific problem.

Comment: actually i have used proper instructions and to be honest i am getting a lot of connections but after a while is just gets stuck when i try to get a connection. i may not be closing the connection properly. i do a conn.close method to close the connection and do not use ConnectionManager.closeConnection method(). its something to do with Db connection leaking. not sure what

Answer (score 0):

That code is virtually guaranteed to cause connection leaks in a multithreaded system. `closeDbConnection()` closes only the last connection borrowed from pool - so if 10 threads have called `getDbConnection()`, and after that `closeDbConnection()`, only 1 connection is closed and 9 still alive. Repeat that several times and pool is exhausted (unless connection is cleaned up in `finalize()`, but that's probably not the case). I would get rid of the whole class, or reworked it to act only as a datasource locator.

Comment: my bad.... actually what i do in my client code is that i get the connection using conn = ConnectionManager.getInstance().getDbConnection(); and after using it i do conn.close(). the closeDbConnection() is never used. i hope doing conn.close is appropriate ??? or how else should i close the connections?

Comment: Hm, that should be fine then. Check you're closing connection in the `finally` block - maybe an exception is thrown  that prevents closing the connection.